# click next and previous to show overflow div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a lot of `overflow:hidden;` items, how can I show `overflow:hidden;` items when I click next and previous like in my example below? I would also like to have moving forward and backward effect. I have tried some plugin but it doesn't work when I click next and prev. Any idea of how to do that easily ?

```css
.container{
    width:580px;
  height:70px;
  background:#ccc;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  }

.item{
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:5;
    background:#fff;
    margin:5px;
    padding-top:10px;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
  }

.prev , .next{
  cursor:pointer;
  width:50px;
  }

.prev:hover , .next:hover{
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  }
```

```html
<div class="prev">Prev</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
<div class="next">Next</div>
```

Comment: Can you display your attempts of doing this please?

Comment: I guess your sample code not working. Is this what you want http://callmenick.com/_development/responsive-content-slider/ . If you require something else, provide the proper working sample